# Java nio AclEntry. How to know if principal is group or user

Tags: java, permissions, acl

I'm using java.nio.file.attribute.AclFileAttributeView and AclEntry in order to collect all files ACL on a system. Things are quite straight forward until I realized the library has no method to check whether the principal is an user or a group.

The function needs to only return user (not group) that has read permission, do you have any suggestion?

Here is the draft of my code

```
public String[] getViewer(String path)
{
    // List of the ACL enum of read permission
    List<AclEntryPermission> readAcl = new ArrayList<AclEntryPermission>();
    readAcl.add(AclEntryPermission.READ_ATTRIBUTES);
    readAcl.add(AclEntryPermission.READ_DATA);
    readAcl.add(AclEntryPermission.SYNCHRONIZE);
    readAcl.add(AclEntryPermission.READ_NAMED_ATTRS);

    AclFileAttributeView acl = Files.getFileAttributeView(Paths.get(path),
            AclFileAttributeView.class);
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (acl!=null)
    {   
        try {
            List<AclEntry> aclList = acl.getAcl();
            for (AclEntry entry: aclList)
            {
                //System.out.println(a.principal() + ":");
                //System.out.println(entry.permissions() + "\n");
                if (entry.permissions().containsAll(readAcl))
                {   
                    // Only add principal if it is not a group
                    if (entry.principal.isGroup())
                    names.add(entry.principal().getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return names.toArray(new String[]{});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just answer your question, checking GroupPrincipal is possible. You can just use

```
if (entry.principal() instanceof GroupPrincipal)
```

to check.

However, I don't see what you can do with this checking result.

Comment: Thanks, I use it for group look up in the AD.